# Google Location Accuracy datafeed

Tags: wifi, geolocation, google-apps

Since Android 9, there is an option in your location preferences which is called
*Location Accuracy*.

[image]

I [know how Google determines my location](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro) over wifi and now I wonder if *Location Accuracy* has **also** the purpose of feeding new locations of accesspoints to Google.

Is this correct? 
If yes, has anybody an official statement to that?

If no, how does Google refresh their location-data of APs(, besides wardriving)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wonder if Location Accuracy has also the purpose of feeding new
>   locations of accesspoints to Google.

Yes,When you select the option to pin point you they use a wide variety of things.When it does do they also send data to better those services.Google initially started mapping wifi points using [cars.](https://www.zdnet.com/article/how-to-keep-your-wi-fi-location-out-of-google/)

> This summer it was revealed that Google Street View cars, besides
>   taking photos of your neighborhood, were also collecting the street
>   addresses, Wi-Fi service set identifier (SSID), and the unique Media
>   Access Control (MAC) identification information for computers, Wi-Fi
>   access points (AP)s, and routers

As for using your data to better their geo location services is also true.
Here is the official statement of [such](https://policies.google.com/technologies/location-data)

> Most mobile phones are equipped with GPS, which uses signals from
>   satellites to determine a device’s location – however, with Google
>   Location Services, additional information from nearby Wi-Fi, mobile
>   networks, and device sensors can be collected to determine your
>   device’s location. **It does this by periodically collecting location
>   data from your device and using it in an anonymous way to improve
>   location accuracy.**